# How did we get ‘deft’ and ‘daffy’ from “daft”?

Tags: etymology, differences, semantics, semantic-shift

> [[ Etymonline for 'daft (adj.)']](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=daft&allowed_in_frame=0) Old English *gedæfte* "gentle, becoming," ... from PIE * *dhabh-* "to fit together" (see [fabric](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fabric&allowed_in_frame=0)). Sense of "mild, well-mannered" (c. 1200).
>
> [[ Etymonline for 'daffy']](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=daffy&searchmode=none) 1884, perhaps from [daft](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=daft&allowed_in_frame=0) (adj.), or from obsolete *daffe* "a halfwit"

The Oxford University Press website makes the following observations

> [[Blog.oup.com:]](http://blog.oup.com/2013/09/etymology-word-origin-daft-deft-silly-fool/) **Daft** goes back to Old English, in which its sense was “mild, gentle, meek”    (the root, again on the evidence of Gothic, meant “be, become fit”). Why “fit, suitable” yielded “stupid” and “bereft of sound judgment” is far from clear; nor does the presence of Middle Engl. *`daff`* “simpleton, fool” of unknown origin dispel the obscurity. To confuse us even more, we notice that **daft** is a doublet of **deft**. Originally, **deft** also meant “gentle, meek,” later “skillful; neat; pretty.” The starting point of **daft** and **deft** was the same, namely “fitting, convenient.” ...

**Daft** and **deft** are antonyms, but I always mistake one for the other.

- How can I avoid mixing the two up?

I also included ‘daffy’ because I'm unsure if the OUP blog's citation of 'Middle English *`daff`*' refers to ‘daffy’. Does it?

Comment: The only obvious common thread here is a synonym for gentle and mild: "soft".  From there, it's easy to see how "daffy" could evolve from "soft in the head".

Comment: Are you looking for something like a mnemonic for this pair? I think you have everything you need in your explanation already, 'daft' is closer to 'Daffy Duck'. That is, I see nothing in the vowel difference, mid-front and open front, that meaningfully separates the two (the difference and connection to meaning is arbitrary).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I thank you for your edit, but weep over the downvote.

Comment: @Mitch I welcome a mnemonic, but I meant to emphasise that I didn't find everything I needed above. For example, the OUP blog post concedes `Why “fit, suitable” yielded “stupid” and “bereft of sound judgment” is far from clear`. So how did it? I'll read the helpful answer below now.

Comment: "Deft" is most often seen in the adverb form -- "deftly".  "The pickpocket deftly relieved the man of his billfold."

Comment: I was hoping that both the question and the answer would have attracted more upvotes, I quite like the question and the answer is really tip top quality. You were very fortunate to receive such a gem of an answer!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Many thanks for your support. I relish this answer; I hope to be able to imagine more etymologies myself based on it, lest I annoy too many here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Metaphorical extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphorical_extension)* does amazing things to cause a root meaning to radiate out in various directions, quoting the linguist Jeffrey Henning:

> Radiation is metaphorical extension on a grander scale, with new
>   meanings radiating from a central semantic core to embrace many
>   related ideas.
>
> - The word ***head*** originally referred to that part of the
>     human body above the rest.
> - Since the top of a nail, pin or screw is,
>     like the human head, the top of a slim outline, that sense has become
>     included in the meaning of ***head***.
> - Since the bulb of a cabbage or
>     lettuce is round like the human head, that sense has become included
>     in the meaning of ***head***.
> - Know where I'm ***headed*** with this?
> - The meaning of the word head has radiated out to include the ***head*** of a coin (the
>     side picturing the human head), the ***head*** of the list (the top item in
>     the list), the ***head*** of a table, the ***head*** of the family, a ***head*** of
>     cattle, $50 a ***head***
>
> *Wikipedia **emphasis** mine and reformatted for clarity*

*[Semantic deterioration](https://www.uni-due.de/SHE/HE_Change_Semantic.htm)* also shifts words from their root meaning:

> A disapprovement in the meaning of a word.
>
> - The term *knave* meant originally (Old English) ‘*male servant*’ from    ‘boy’ (cf. German Knabe) but deteriorated to the meaning of
>     ‘*base or coarse person*’, having more or less died out and been
>     replaced by *boy*.
> - *Villain* developed from ‘*inhabitant of a village*’ to ‘*scoundrel*’.
> - The word *peasant* is used now for someone who shows bad behaviour as      the word *farmer* has become the normal term. In official contexts, however, the term ‘*peasant*’ is found for small and/or poor *farmers*.
>
> *Types of Semantic Change,* University of Duisburg-Essen, Reformatted for clarity.

*[Semantic amelioration](https://www.uni-due.de/SHE/HE_Change_Semantic.htm#types)* shifts words in the opposite direction:

> An improvement in the meaning of a word.
>
> - The term *nice* derives from Latin *nescius* ‘ignorant’ and came at    the time of its borrowing from Old French to mean ‘silly, simple’ then ‘foolish, stupid’, later developing a more positive meaning as ‘pleasing, agreeable’.
>
> *Types of Semantic Change,* University of Duisburg-Essen, Reformatted for clarity.

In this case, these three forces seem to radiate the meaning of two words from the root in opposing directions:

The etymological theory, which is plausible though not 100% certain, suggests that the PIE [*dhabh*-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dhabh-&searchmode=none) "*to fit together*" developed slowly toward its present *[deft](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deft)*- "*skillful*" by  a **metaphorical extension** of the *gentle skills* used to *fit together* *[fabric](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fabric&allowed_in_frame=0)*, a word that shares the same PIE root *dhabh*-. That metaphorical extension is intuitively understood in the picture of a *deft* boy:

[image]
*Photo © Jena P. Jones/f2photos.com*

Apparently, *deft* and *daft* shared a sense of "*gentle, and becoming*" in Old English. Their different pronunciations (which only later formalized into [spellings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform#History)) experienced different **metaphorical extension** in Middle English. *Deft* continued to develop the meaning of "*skillful*".

But *daft* seems to have experienced systematic **semantic deterioration** from "*mild-mannered*" (1200), to "*dull and awkward*" (1300), and eventually to "*foolish and crazy*" (1500) under the added influence of the third word *daffy*. In the same way that the weaker children at school become *awkward* in the presence of the stronger children, we can **imagine** some *mild-mannered* people being oppressed by skillful manipulators, who label themselves *deft*, and their victims *daft*. Continuing this pattern of derogatory differentiation over generations would reinforce the semantic deterioration of *daft*:

[image]
*jackfrost.blog.co.uk*

It is not certain, but it seems reasonable that *[daffy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=daffy&allowed_in_frame=0)* developed from *daft*. The [adjective suffix -y](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-y&allowed_in_frame=0) indicates "full of or characterized by," and eventually the sense of diminutive [pet suffix -y](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-y#-y-2) may have added to the semantic deterioration of *daffy*.  Even if the direct source of *daffy* was not *daft*, but rather *daffe* - "*a halfwit*", the phonetic analogy of *daft* and *daffy* could have easily added to the semantic deterioration of *daft*.

This *metaphorical extension*, *semantic deterioration* and *analogy* took place over time, only becoming obvious to us by [comparative linguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_linguistics). The way people used the words *deft* and *daft* slowly changed, until their meanings became opposite, and the way people used *daffy* reinforced the distinction.

---

**Recommended Reading**: [*Analogy and Morphological Change*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0748646213), by David Fertig

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively for your support. I'll try to obtain that recommended book. May I please ask whether you have more general advice for me? The main problem appears my dullness; I wouldn't have been able to guess or imagine all the morphological changes that you have been charitably explaining to me. Then again, I never studied linguistics. I'll read more about it, but am unsure if it can empower me to deduce as much as you do!

Comment: You don't strike me as dull at all, @LawArea51Proposal-Commit. Your interest and inquisitive pursuit of etymology will create a deeper understanding of meaning in the words you read and use. You seem to prefer linear logical certainty, which can inhibit your understanding of the intuitive emotional developments in language, but the fact that your approach is evidence-based is helpful. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Many thanks! I value your constructive criticism! I'll try to think more 'laterally', instead of 'linearly'. How can I deepen my imagination though? I envy your proficiency in capturing all the gaps in the etymology, but I still grapple with so many words.

Comment: I kind of wonder how much anti-Welsh feeling there may be in the roots of _daffy_ and _daft_. Think of Daffyd's Day, daffodils, and the old English children's rhyme that starts "Taffy was a Welshman; Taffy was a thief". Of course, _Taffy_ is _Daffyd_ with an English spin.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... I think there should be more similar sounding antonyms...